# MPAndroidChart: Change Shape of Bar Chart

Tags: android, kotlin

i already read answers of question that similar to mine.
but, i don't understand and i think that's so complex. maybe some of you have a trick how to make it simple. i am using **`'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'`** library, btw. i want to make a bar chart style like this picture.

[image: the bar chart]

the corner of rectangle has radius about `4dp`.
i haven't found any method to draw that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no way to make it simple. Finally I came up with a clumsy, but working solution which worked well in my case.
First subclass the BarChartRenderer and set it to your chart:

```
class CustomBarRenderer constructor(
         chart: BarChart, 
         animator: ChartAnimator, 
         vpHandler: ViewPortHandler,
         cornerDimens: Float
) : BarChartRenderer(chart, animator, vpHandler)

//...
chart.renderer = CustomBarRenderer(chart, chart.animator, chart.viewPortHandler, cornersDimens)
//...
```

`BarChartRenderer` inherits `mRenderPaint` member which is used to draw bar lines, so if you need some slight modification (bar border width, fill type or anything else) you can simply override `mRendererPaint` in your `init` block and you're good to go.

```
init {
    mRendererPaint = Paint().also {
        // all paint properties you need
    }
}
```

But this is not enough to get that rounded corners bars. The reason is that renderer draws them using `canvas.drawRect` inside `drawDataSet` method, so we need to go deeper and override it and change this invocation to `canvas.drawRoundRect`:

```
override fun drawDataSet(c: Canvas, dataSet: IBarDataSet, index: Int) {

    //....
    c.drawRoundRect(
         buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
         buffer.buffer[j + 3], cornersDimen, cornersDimen, mRenderPaint
    )
    //....
}
```

**Important** - although the majority of `renderer`'s members are `protected` and easy to use or override, there are still some `private` stuff which is used for drawing shadows. Unfortunately I had to just remove shadows rendering (in first place just because I didn't need them), so for somebody this could be an incomplete solution.

Comment: what is `buffer` and `j` ?

Comment: @VLeonovs You need to check `BarChartRenderer` source first. `buffer` is an internal member of it and `j` is a counter to render certain bar inside a loop. Actually, if everything you need is just a rounded bar - you don't need to know anything about them, just replace `drawRect` with `drawRoundRect` and pass value for corners.

Answer (score 0):

Created a complete rounded edge of bar chart MPAndroidChart,Please check below link:-

[Rounded edge of barchart](https://gist.github.com/xanscale/e971cc4f2f0712a8a3bcc35e85325c27)