# Implementing custom barchart in android

Tags: java, android-studio, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, axis-labels

I'm trying to implement a custom barchart

[image]

which should look exactly like this. I tried mpChart but could only get this far

[image]

```
    barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "");
    barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    barData.setBarWidth(.5f);
    barChart.setData(barData);
    
  barDataSet.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    barDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    barDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false); 
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false); 
    barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    barChart.setDescription(null);
    barChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    barChart.setExtraOffsets(20, 0, 0, 30);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTextSize(14f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    xAxis.setYOffset(5);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setXOffset(30);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel));
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    
    barChart.invalidate();
```

I tried almost all possible examples and questions here, couldn't get the label to centre of the bars. Is it possible to put the labels exactly below the bars in non grouped bars? all the solutions I saw is only for grouped bars or combined charts.

Comment: are you trying to make it yourself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was plotting the x axis values from 1. when changed it to 0 and removed

```
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
```

and i was able to centre the axis labels

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom renderer for it.

Subclass BarChartRenderer and then call:

barChart.setRenderer(new MyBarChartRenderer(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler()))

It will even allow you to alter the shape of it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369115/mpandroidchart-change-shape-of-bar-chart/55392212#55392212).

But I think what you're looking for comes really close to [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/4732).

Answer (score 0):

Download the MPAndroidChart Source from [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases/tag/v3.0.3). Then, you can customize the code according to your need and add it your project by
Clicking on File>New>Import Module.