# MPChart Android - Custom Bar Graph UI

Tags: android, graph, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have gone through the MPAndroidChart library in android :
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Its really powerful library for Graph and Chart implementation in android.

I have to display the Bar Graph as below :

[image]

What I have achieved is :

[image]

The Question is can I customise the Bars to as shown in my above image. i.e. in rounded corner shape?

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369115/mpandroidchart-change-shape-of-bar-chart

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
    RoundedBarChartRenderer roundedBarChartRenderer = new RoundedBarChartRenderer(mContext, barChart,
            barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler(), true);

    roundedBarChartRenderer.setmRadius(50f);

    barChart.setRenderer(roundedBarChartRenderer);

    barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);
```